# Why does pytorch F.mse_loss behave differently w.r.t. Tensor and Parameter?

Tags: pytorch

Below is my code:

```
import torch as pt
from torch.nn import functional as F

a = pt.Tensor([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
b = pt.Tensor([[1, 0], [5, 4]])
print(F.mse_loss(a, b), F.mse_loss(a, b, reduction='elementwise_mean'))

a = pt.nn.Parameter(a)
b = pt.nn.Parameter(b)
print(F.mse_loss(a, b), F.mse_loss(a, b, reduction='elementwise_mean'))
```

The output was:

```
tensor(3.) tensor(3.)
tensor(12., grad_fn=<SumBackward0>) tensor(12., grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
```

I wonder why they gave two different results?

Environment setting:
python 3.6
pytorch 0.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug according to [pytorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-does-f-mse-loss-behave-differently-w-r-t-tensor-and-parameter/22720/2).